# I have a list of objects but I can't find a way to tidy up my code. I'm trying to update an object at a specific index in C#

Tags: c#, generics

### **Summary**

My problem is this; I want to make my code neat and tidy because otherwise I'll get an earful (be told how to do it properly). Given I kind of need to get this working in a relatively short time frame, I would appreciate some advice. I'll admit to only doing a quick google search before asking the question, so my bad. But still, advice would be helpful.

### **Code**

```
    itemList[Int32.Parse(SearchName.Text) - 1]{
        Name = UserInput;
        Price = UserInputPrice;
    };
```

### **Goal**

To actually get this working. I don't know if I can do this, with the braces and all. If I could do this, it'd make updating it as I try to add more functions to it a lot easier, but if I can't, I could just replicate with a less neat alternative.

Again, sorry for my lack of research. I'd appreciate any help or suggestions you can give me. I'm new to C#. Also, these are not my real variables, this is just an example of what I'd like to do.

### Original/Working Code

```
    itemList[Int32.Parse(SearchName.Text) - 1].Name = textBox6.Text;
    itemList[Int32.Parse(SearchName.Text) - 1].Price = Int32.Parse(textBox5.Text);
    itemList[Int32.Parse(SearchName.Text) - 1].Cost = Int32.Parse(textBox4.Text);
    itemList[Int32.Parse(SearchName.Text) - 1].Stock = Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text);
```

These are all at the same index. I am trying to cut down the code so I only have to specify the location in the list once.

Comment: What you have written is not even valid C#. - Jane Smith.

Comment: write the ugly code (that actually compiles), and we'll all go fashion week on it

Comment: I am aware it's not valid. If it was valid I wouldn't be asking whether I can achieve something similar.

Comment: But... because its not valid, we have no idea what you are trying to do, well its harder to guess

Comment: are you trying to create a new object in an array?

Comment: This is a generic list set to the type Product (A class I'm using). The aim is to update the object's values at a user indicated index. The code at the bottom is what I am using at the moment and trying to cut down into a neater way of writing it. I can't seem to see a way of doing it. Apologies for the poorly worded/written question. The textboxes with the numbers is because I got lazy. I will fix them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is, don't worry about looking neat, worry about getting it to compile.

Secondly, if you take user input, it can be wrong, check it, tell the user about it. Use `TryParse`.

```
// do this for every int
if (!int.TryParse(SearchName.Text, out var myFavoriteNumber))
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Woah {SearchName.Text} is not even a number!");
    return;
}
```

Long lines of array indexers look ugly, consider referencing the item, or using a helper method to fill them

```
var myFavoriteObject = itemList[myFavoriteNumber - 1];

myFavoriteObject.Name = name;
myFavoriteObject.Price = myNotherFavoriteNumber;
```

The key to neat code, is readable code, which is also maintainable code. People tend to want to put everything on one like because they have some sort of OCD, but the truth is, simple readable code beats fancy code every time.

Opinionated 2 cents given

Comment: A question before this all goes, what is the use of {  in the code? I've seen them but never got any real explanation.

Comment: I second this answer; I would prefer it to be readable than tidy myself.  It does sometimes feels like a game to develop as less verbose as possible and it's fun but in reality it's just not as maintainable at times.  I do prefer to use the ```if TryParse``` within the scope of success instead of ```if not TryParse```.

Comment: @JohnSmith that's called string interpolation, means you can embed variables in string literals

Comment: ... as long as the string literal is proceeded by the dollar sign $.

Comment: What @MichaelPuckettII said

Comment: Thank you. That makes other things I am planning on doing easier to implement. Thank you for this answer. You've saved me some grief, sorry for the poor question, I just wanted to be able to read it easier in future.

Comment: @JohnSmith As far as some questions go here, you nearly won the newbie of the day award, i.e it was not a bad worded question (in the end)

Comment: I am not usually this daft, I promise. Anyhow, thank you. I do usually put research into things. Just today I needed it done in about an hour. So you've saved me some grief. I thought you were taking the mickey.